Delphi ambiguous call of functions
I need to find out where can be wrong function called.
I use this construct for years in thousands of places:
var mQuery:TIBOQuery;
begin
  mQuery := CreateQuery(FirebirdTransaction);
  try
    with mQuery, mQuery.SQL do begin
      Clear;
      Add('SELECT POKLADNA FROM HOMEBANKING_EXPORT_POLOZKY WHERE POKLADNA = :JEDIN');
      ParamByName('JEDIN').Value := Jedin;
      Open;
      Result := Active and not IsEmpty;
      Close;
    end;
  finally
    mQuery.Free;
  end;
end;

Actually I am working on upgrade from Delphi 11.3 to 12.1, but Embarcadero added function TStrings.IsEmpty in Delphi.Athens and it makes a problem on many places where I expect to call TDataSet.IsEmpty instead of TStrings.IsEmpty from "mQuery.SQL".
Is it possible to turn on some compiler mechanism which will rather not compile this project than to simply compile with many "surprises" of ambiguous calls?

Nitpick: TStrings.IsEmpty, not TString.IsEmpty. In any case, this is a great example of why you should never use with statements, and especially not multiple ones.

I would rather to expect from compiler to see, that there are more functions accessible and to stop compiler when ambiguous calls.

There is nothing ambiguous for compiler as it uses scoping rules here and calls ToString method from the closest scope. In this case the last variable in the with clause that implements that function. The only way to deal with this is to refactor code in Delphi 11.3 and remove all double with clauses. Preferably even single ones.

@DalijaPrasnikar you are right in principle: The compiler does not consider this ambiguous, but it would be safer if it did.

The lesson here is: using shortcuts has its price. If the compiler should warn/error on ambiguity then any code should also use () on a function/procedure/method which don't have parameters to make it unambiguous from a variable/property/constant. And this also open's the can of worms to if this. must be used far more often.

Read the Q and all As in Is Delphi "with" keyword a bad practice?

Quit using WITH and get cleaner code.
https://ideasawakened.com/post/why-you-should-not-use-WITH-in-your-Delphi-code

If you want to resolve ambiguous call you should stop using "with"
var mQuery:TIBOQuery;
begin
  mQuery := CreateQuery(FirebirdTransaction);
  try
    mQuery.SQL.Clear;
    mQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT POKLADNA FROM HOMEBANKING_EXPORT_POLOZKY WHERE POKLADNA = :JEDIN');
    mQuery.ParamByName('JEDIN').Value := Jedin;
    mQuery.Open;
    Result := mQuery.Active and not mQuery.IsEmpty;
    mQuery.Close;
  finally
    mQuery.Free;
  end;
end;

The added benefit is that you now can inspect your variables while debugging.

When you use C# .NET it cannot happen, because compiler writes about ambiguous calls. If .NET can do that, I think it is possible to do it for Delphi as well.

But Delphi simply is not .NET! File a feature request to Embarcadero.

@rotursoft Does C# even have a with feature like Pascal?

@AmigoJack Of couse it does not have WITH statement, but using scope to more namespaces can raise the same problem.

@KenWhite, where is it documented that with is deprecated?

@PhilipJ.Rayment: It seems to me that it was in one of the text files that is in the Delphi folder. IIRC, it was around the time that they made a breaking change to the compiler.  (Can't remember offhand what that change was - it's been several years now. If it comes back to me, I'll drop another comment here.) I don't think it was a firm deprecation, but a warning that it might be in the future, so you should get away from using it. I've hated with since the first time someone used it and it bit me in the backside like it did the poster here, and I removed it everywhere I came across it.

@KenWhite, I recall on Quality Portal suggestions that it be abolished, and the response was that they had no intention of doing that.  I love with and it saves a fair bit of typing.  Like with other things (e.g. order of used units), you do have to be careful using it, but that's not, in my mind, reason to avoid using it.  The help actually says that it's more efficient in certain cases: "If the interpretation of obj involves indexing arrays or dereferencing pointers, these actions are performed once, before statement is executed. This makes with statements efficient as well as concise."

@PhilipJ.Rayment Not using with saves a fair bit of thinking (and ctrl-clicking to determine where an identifier is declared in an unfamiliar code base). Rule number one is "Don't make me think"

@GerryColl Programming requires thinking!  And no, using with does not require any more thinking at all, depending on how you use it.  Even though I touch-type, I find thinking easier and quicker than typing, most of the time.

@PhilipJ.Rayment When faced with a 500 line procedure written by idiots with multiple nested with statements it adds accidental/avoidable complexity (see Fred Brook's 'No Silver Bullets' essay). It make the intent of a statement unclear without further research. As shown above, it can cause breaking changes to your code. Typing is much easier than thinking for most people. If I see FieldByName('Description).AsString := NewName;I have no idea what dataset it applies to without scrolling up to see what the activewith` statement is. This happens to me all of the time!

@GerryColl I did say "depending on how you use it".  Clearly multiple nested with statements are likely to be hard to debug (as would be 500-line procedures), but that doesn't mean that all situations will be like that.
